# Allow only the EXACT user of the post to edit it

Tags: php

Supposed that I have a *posts* table like this:

```
post_id       topic_id       user_id     content         date
 1               7            12         bla bla         7/15/2014
 2               16           70         bla bla         7/16/2014
 3               7            14         bloa bla        7/20/2014
```

In which the user_id is the foreign key of the *users* table.

Assume that I could record the user session by using `$_SESSION['user_id']` after he signs into his account to perform the **EDIT** action (via the edit.php page). And assume that I can get `($_GET)` the post_id into the hyperlink edit.php?id=1 for editing.

As you can see, each `user_id` has got a certain `post_id`, and unique logged-in session. My problem is that, for example, when Mr.Eric `(user_id #12)` browses his own post `(post_id#1)` **does a trick** by manually changes `edit.php?id=1` to `edit.php?id=2`, then he edits the post_id #2 whose user_id is actually user_id#70, which is **NOT ALLOWED** logically.

I did try the following query, but i failed to check the correct user session as i wished:

```
$q="SELECT user_id, post_id, content
        FROM posts
        WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
        ";

$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$uid = isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : -1;
$current_user = $row['user_id'];
}

if(!$uid && $uid != $current_user){
   echo 'sorry, but this is not your own post for editing!';
}
```

Can you help, please? Thank you!

Comment: var_dump() your $uid and $current_user, compare it.

Comment: You check if the variable is defined in your loop. You don't check for that in your SQL. You last if statement says if its false (which it never will be, because you either assign it to the user id of the logged in user, or -1 (neither are false unless your user ID is zero - falsy).

Comment: @crowler: I define it in the `while loop`, but still failed. Not sure if it's correct or not? The code is `if (!defined('edit') ) { if (!$uid && $uid != $current_user) { ... }  define('edit', TRUE);}` **Can you help with the actually one as an answer?** I am really stuck!

Comment: @HendraLim: After doing the `var_dump()` and compare them, it shows like this `string(1) "1" string(2) "70" string(2) "70" string(1) "1"`. *Can you help my with the correct conditional*, please?

Comment: do u put var_dump() inside while loop?

Comment: @HendraLim: Yes, I put the `var_dump($current_user)` inside the `WHILE` loop only, because I think that the variable `current_user` was just created for the loop result checking. Sorry, but am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `&&` in `if(!$uid && $uid != $current_user){` should be `||`.

The line looks like its saying in pseudocode, `if $uid doesn't exist AND $uid does not equal $current user do something, otherwise, do nothing`.  $uid DOES exist in your example so it'll return FALSE and skip your whole `if`.

That means the $uid doesn't have to match $current_user, it just has to exist and it can edit anything.

Comment: I try this, but fail!